# asp.net mvc update webpage from server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to do is force a webpage to update with new content without refreshing when it is set on the server.

Ideally a user would be looking at a blank page that would update with specific content when it is set on the server or in the database.

Any ideas on how I could go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, the client (ie the web browser) would poll the server every so often to fetch new data.

However, there are a number of server push frameworks out there. Have a look at the following article on [COMET](http://ajaxian.com/archives/comet-a-new-approach-to-ajax-applications). I believe this is used by such sites as [meebo](http://www.meebo.com) and [Chess.com](http://www.chess.com) (for playing live chess online in the browser).

Comment: i had completely forgotten about simply polling but I think COMET would be something cool to check out, thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a jQuery Ajax call to poll the server every X seconds checking for new content.  When the call returns, it would append/prepend the content to the page automatically.

Comment: Server push (streaming) is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to poll the server for new content or use [comet](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wxv_comet.aspx)

Neither are particularly beautiful solutions, but the web is "connectionless" for now but there are ways round it.